# How to create group of users and link group policy to them via powershell/cmd Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: powershell, cmd, group-policy

Is there a way to create group of users with group policy apllied to them via Powershell/CMD?
My machine is not joined to a domain.
I want to prepare a script which I will use multiple times on other local computers/ machines to recreate group policy.
I want e.g restrict user access to Control Panel, Internet Access and stuff like that.

Thanks from advance for answers

Comment: Please, check the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For computers not joined to the domain, you can't use Group Policy. You will need to use Local Policy. Many of the items that you are looking for will simply be registry value that you can easily set with a PowerShell script. For example the policy for Hiding Fast User Switching toggles can be toggled like this:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" -Name HideFastUserSwitching -Value 0
```

You can look up where the values are by reading the .admx templates

Alternatively you could use [David Wyatt's PowerShell module](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Read-or-modify-Registrypol-778fed6e) to read and modify policy files.

Finally the last option would be create the policy on one computer and then overwrite the .pol files on all the computers and then `gpupdate /force`. This of course could be scripted with PowerShell.

```
Copy-Item \\ExampleComputer1\C$\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Registry.pol \\ExampleComputer2\C$\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Registry.pol -Force
Copy-Item \\ExampleComputer1\C$\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Registry.pol \\ExampleComputer2\C$\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Registry.pol -Force
```

Security Templates would have to be exported from the Security Templates mmc snapin and then imported on the other computers with `secedit`

```
secedit /configure /db %temp%\temp.sdb /cfg yourcreated.inf
```

Comment: Using that solution --> Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" -Name HideFastUserSwitching -Value 0

Answer (score 0):

Using that solution --> Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" -Name HideFastUserSwitching -Value 0

Doesn't work. 
I mean e.g:

Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\NonEnum" -Name NoRecycleBinIcon -Value 1

[.admx template.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U97VK.png)

It should make my desktop recyclebin gone. This is just an example other settings also stays unchanged.

Comment: I was switching '0' and '1'  - also no reaction

Comment: This doesn't take effect until Group Policy is reapplied. Did you restart or run `gpupdate /force` after changing it? Also the answer section is reserved for answers, this should be a comment or added to your question.

Comment: Sorry I'm a newbie on the stack :). Yes I did restart and use gpupdate/force.I'm investingating on this but cannot find the reason why this commands don't affect.

Comment: I didn't find the solution for the first method. So I decided to use  David Wyatt's PowerShell module + Brandon Padgett approach --> (http://brandonpadgett.com/powershell/Local-gpo-powershell/) and everything works very well ! Thank you for your help !!!